# 英語が残っている: CAPTCHAにひっかかったときのメッセージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

先ほど投稿するときCAPTCHAにひっかかったのですが、その時に英語のメッセージで「CAPTCHAをしないといけない」などと書かれたものが出てきました。

性質上再現は困難です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく https://ja.traducir.win/string/1480 だと思われます。翻訳しておきました :)

Key: 2a223bd041140757afb3f2b65e76aa6b

Comment: あともう1つ、長い英文があったはずです。

Comment: @apple502j さん、なるほど、Traducir にある string の中で "CAPTCHA" という文字列を含んでいるのは4つしかないので、Traducir に無い string かもしれません。 https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=CAPTCHA

Comment: https://ja.traducir.win/string/4660 かも知れないですね。翻訳の提案を出しておきました（ほぼ以前の翻訳そのままです）。

Answer (score 1):

CAPTCHAが出せましたので、参考まで。

> [image: CAPTCHA画面]

モバイル版:

> [image: モバイル版CAPTCHA画面]